# Android StudioでRobotActivityが使えなくなった。

Tags: android-studio, pepper

Android Studioでpepperの開発を行おうとしたらこれまでは"Robot"と入力すれば
RobotActivityが出てきたのですが出なくなりました。
AndroidSDKに問題があるのでしょうか？下記にAndroidSDKのチェックしている所を記入します。

・SDK Platforms
Android 10.0(Q)

-Show Package Details
Android 10.0(Q)→
Android SDK Platform 29
Sources for Android 29
Android 6.0(Marshmallow)→
Android SDK Platform 23
Google APIs Intel x86 Atom System Image

・SDK Tools
Android SDK Build-Tools 30
Android SDK Platform-Tools

-Show Package Details
Android SDK Build-Tools 30→
29.0.3
23.0.3
CMake→
Android SDK Platform-Tools

その他にも原因として考えられそうなところがあれば教えいただけると助かります。

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`RobotActivity` というのが具体的に何なのか分かりませんが、おそらく
`com.aldebaran.qi.sdk.design.activity.RobotActivity` のことだと仮定します。

まず以下を参考に、**Pepper SDK Plugin** を正しくインストールしてください。
Windowsの場合は**Bonjour**や**MSVCランタイム**のインストールも必要となります。

- [Installing the Pepper SDK plug-in — QiSDK](https://qisdk.softbankrobotics.com/sdk/doc/pepper-sdk/ch1_gettingstarted/installation.html)

ちなみに上記リファレンスにも記載されているように、Android StudioのSDK ManagerからインストールするAndroid SDKは、最新安定版（Android 10対応のPlatform 29とBuild-Tools 29.0.x）だけで十分です。新しいバージョンのSDKでは、build.gradle にて`minSdkVersion`の設定を変えるだけで、古いバージョンのAndroid OSにも対応したアプリを開発できます。SDK Platform 30/Build-Tools 30はAndroid 11対応バージョンですが、現時点ではまだOS/SDKともにベータ版なので、試験目的でない限り使わないほうがよいです。

次に以下を参考に、適当な Activity を持つプロジェクトを作成してから **Robot Application** を作成します。
これにより、build.gradle には自動的にQiSDKへの依存関係が追加されます。

- [Creating a robot application — QiSDK](https://qisdk.softbankrobotics.com/sdk/doc/pepper-sdk/ch1_gettingstarted/starting_project.html)